# django GET last_login time of 1 user and list of all user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, aggregation-framework, http-post

I want to get  last_login of actuel user and list of all users .
this is my login view :

```
def loginPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password =request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')

        context = {}
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)
```

and this is my user table :
[image: user table]

any advices ?

Comment: But that field _does_ get updated automatically when a user logs in. You have `django.contrib.auth` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting yes?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes bro its does . now how can i find the last user login from the all users list ?